# Adjusting frame of controls programmatically

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am using UIButton control through xib file. Now I want to set the frame of button programmatically. I have tried below

```
btn.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,200,70);
```

It doesn't change the position and stays on the same X and Y co-ordinates where I have placed in the XIB file.

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: In the debugger, can you see that btn is properly initialised? If you type `po btn` you should see details about the button, including its current frame.

Comment: @Fogmeister - I am not using Auto Layout

Comment: @Clafou - Yes, button is properly initialized

Comment: this button might be sub view of another subview. Please make sure this button is sub view of super view (default view of VC)

Comment: No. Its the subview of the superview(default view of VC) only

Comment: @Clafou - I have placed button in the middle of the view in XIB file and in DidLoad method, I am setting frame to (0,0,20,40), and when I wrote po btn;,it gave me <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x1659f860; frame = (55 158; 70 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1659fa70>>

Answer (score 0):

Use like this first two parameter represent x,y coordinate for the button and other two represent height and width of the button

```
 btn.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Use auto layout property

Comment: I tried with this. But it is then affecting frames of other controls added programatically

Answer (score 0):

Go to your xib file, select the UIButton and on the right panel, select the first option `File Inspector`. Uncheck the `Use Autolayout` checkbox